# How to make Total Commander see only zip files?

Tags: windows, total-commander

I do know is possible, I remember I have done it by mistake once. I want to see only zip files and folders. nothing more. how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Show → Custom...*** and enter **`*.zip`**

Comment: Key-combo would be ctrl-F12 for setting, and ctrl-F10 for resetting to *.*

Answer (score 0):

Change "`*.*`" to "`*.zip`" in your quick filter option just above the list of files and folders.

Comment: that sounds good, but where can I find the quick filter option?

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with the website; it just uses Markdown for formatting and translates `*foo*` to italic type.

Answer (score 0):

(its worth distinguishing between permanent view, or temporary view.)

Temporary view is easy with quicksearch.

See settings for options and hotkeys.

This way I can filter immediately by just pressing: ctrl+alt+s, and then the string to filter by.

With your example, I'd do:

ctrl+alt+s   (and thes press)  zip